# How to select NaN values in pandas in specific range

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [5,6,np.nan, np.nan,np.nan, 4, np.nan, np.nan,np.nan, np.nan,7,8,8, np.nan, 5 , np.nan]})

df: 
    col1
0   5.0
1   6.0
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   4.0
6   NaN
7   NaN
8   NaN
9   NaN
10  7.0
11  8.0
12  8.0
13  NaN
14  5.0
15  NaN
```

These `NaN` values should be replaced in the following way. The first selection should look like this.

```
2   NaN 
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   4.0
6   NaN
7   NaN
8   NaN
9   NaN
```

And then these `Nan` values should be replace with the only value in that selection, 4.
The second selection is:

```
13  NaN
14  5.0
15  NaN
```

and these `NaN` values should be replaced with 5.

With `isnull()` you can select the `NaN` values in a dataframe but how are able to filter/select these specific ranges in pandas?

Comment: Do you need replace missing values if only one ono nan in groups of missing under and behind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution if missing values are around one non missing val - solution create unique groups and replace in groups by forward and back filling:

```
#test missing values
s = df['col1'].isna()
#create unique groups
v = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()
#count groups and get only 1 value around, filter only misising values groups
mask = v.map(v.value_counts()).eq(1) | s
#groups for replacement per groups
g = mask.ne(mask.shift()).cumsum()    

df['col2'] = df.groupby(g)['col1'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
print (df)
    col1  col2
0    5.0   5.0
1    6.0   6.0
2    NaN   4.0
3    NaN   4.0
4    NaN   4.0
5    4.0   4.0
6    NaN   4.0
7    NaN   4.0
8    NaN   4.0
9    NaN   4.0
10   7.0   7.0
11   8.0   8.0
12   8.0   8.0
13   NaN   5.0
14   5.0   5.0
15   NaN   5.0
```